# How do you add a local framework to your carthage framework

Tags: xcode, carthage

The sample project in question can be found here [CarthageExample](https://github.com/miwand/CarthageExample). Basically I have a private framework that I cannot get through Github and would like to know to how to include that in a Carthage build. I believe you can do this with the Cartfile, but I am not sure on how to go about that.The project builds properly but I cannot build the scheme using `carthage build --no-skip-current`, I get a exit code 65 error. When checking the logs it fails on the line that uses a piece of code from the local framework. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide more information about where that framework is. Is it in another git repo, but there's an Xcode project which builds it? Or do you have it as a binary? Carthage can handle both cases in the `Cartfile` using the `git` or `binary` commands.

Comment: Could you also provide the log lines where it fails?